# InvalidProgramException throws on Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am making a webpart that needs to fetch the current user information from active directory using below code:

```
protected void fetchUserInfo()
{
    System.Security.PermissionSet ps = new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
    ps.Assert();

    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext serviceContext = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext.Current;
    UserProfileManager upm = new Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
    ProfileSubtypePropertyManager pspm = upm.DefaultProfileSubtypeProperties;
    string userName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
    UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(userName);

    foreach (ProfileSubtypeProperty prop in pspm.PropertiesWithSection)
    {
    }
}
```

However an InvalidProgramException throws on line         `ProfileSubtypePropertyManager pspm = upm.DefaultProfileSubtypeProperties;`

The error message is:

> Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

I tried googling 
`Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program. sharepointUserProfileManager` but there aren't much info.

What could be the problem?

---

Just now saw that the exception flows on UserProfileManager, so the SPServiceContext isn't valid, and when I look at the property SiteSubscriptionId on serviceContext, I found it was `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

So what does it mean? is there any alternative way to get the current user info from sharepoint?

Comment: Did you try debugging? What is `upm.DefaultProfileSubtypeProperties`? Also, does the service exists, is it accessible?

Comment: @JevgeniGeurtsen The upm.DefaultProfileSubtypeProperties throws the invalidprogramexception

Comment: So it doesn't exists. Is the `upm` instance valid?

Comment: @JevgeniGeurtsen I checked the upm instance and found it isn't valid, please have a look at my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I changed my mind using UserPrincipal to get the user info:

```
    PrincipalContext _principalcontext = GetPrincipalContext();
    UserPrincipal _user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(_principalcontext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, UID);

    if (_user != null)
    {
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = _user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        //Property is here;
    }
```